# Change faker gem phone number format

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, faker

Is there a way to control the format of the Phone number generated by faker?

When I call:

```
Faker::PhoneNumber.cell_phone.to_i
```

I end up getting the wrong value.

I also would like to not have extensions.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can set custom format on the fly like this:

```
Faker::Base.numerify('+90(###) ### ####')
```

This will solve your problem.

Answer (score 7):

[`Faker::PhoneNumber.cell_phone`](https://github.com/stympy/faker/blob/master/lib/faker/phone_number.rb#L12) is basically just calling `numerify` with one of the predefined [`phone_number_formats`](https://github.com/stympy/faker/blob/master/lib/locales/en.yml#L69).

So you could just use `numerify` with your own format.  For e.g. If you want 10 digits number, you would do:

```
Faker.numerify('#########')
```

If you'd still like to use `Faker::PhoneNumber.cell_phone` but would like to get rid of the hyphens, you could use `gsub` to replace the hyphens as:

```
Faker::PhoneNumber.cell_phone.gsub(/-/, '')
```

Comment: You can override this in your own `config/locales/en.yml`.